# Programatically get required values from single product collection

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-collection, programmatically

I am working on module and i want to gather all important values of product related to store and website id. I want name, quantity, barcode, price, special price. I am using following collection query,

```
$collection_check = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
            $collection_check->setStoreId($store_id);
                $collection_check->addWebsiteFilter($website_id);
                $visibility = array(
                Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                );

            $collection_check->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility);

            $cond[] = '{{table}}.is_in_stock=1';  
            $collection_check->joinField(
             'inventory_in_stock',
             'cataloginventory/stock_item',
             'is_in_stock',
             'product_id=entity_id',
             '(' . join(') OR (', $cond) . ')'
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try bellow code**

```
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
        $collection->addStoreFilter();
        $collection->addWebsiteFilter();
        $collection->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addUrlRewrite();

       foreach($collection as $product) {
           print_r($product);
       }
```